# How do I make migrations in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-game-engine, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6.2

My research keeps telling me to use the `Migrate.exe`, which has not shown up in my project, and it cannot be downloaded anywhere. I am also using VS Code and not Visual Studio, which seems to make it impossible to use the Package Manager Console.

And I am using Entity Framework - not Entity Framework Core - so I do not have all the options of EFC.

Currently I am trying to set Entity Framework up in Unity, the game engine. It was possible to set up a temporary project with Entity Framework v6.2.0 and run `dotnet pack` to get the `EntityFramework.dll` but it does not create the `Migrate.exe`. And it seems to be the only option for creating migrations.

Do any of you know how to get the `Migrate.exe` file or another way to add migrations?

Answer (score 2):

> When you install Entity Framework using NuGet migrate.exe will be inside the tools folder of the downloaded package. In \packages\EntityFramework.\tools

Source is [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/migrate-exe)

have you tried this?

Comment: That link sadly did not explain how to actually install EntityFramework, but it did get me looking at trying to install rather than what I had been doing.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a difference in installing and adding, not that they mention that when you look at the package on nuget.org.

So rather than running `dotnet add package EntityFramework --version 6.2.0`
I needed to download the latest nuget.exe from nuget.org and create a packages.config file in the root folder.

I then ran `nuget.exe install packages.config -OutputDirectory packages` which installed all the files I needed.

packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```